# DataGridViewCheckBoxCell question regarding when its value gets assigned

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this function to see if all of a certain columns DataGridViewCheckBoxCell values are True. It however fails because it seems to think the current value is false. I'm running this code in the _CellContentClick event, is there somewhere else I could run this, after it's assigned the value to the cell?

```
Private Function AllTasksAreCompleted() As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean = True

    For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In Me.gridTasks.Rows

        Dim tempCBcell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = GetCheckBoxCell(dgvRow, "colCompleted")
        If Not tempCBcell.Value.ToString = "True" Then
            result = False
            Return result
        End If

    Next

    Return result
```

Thanks a lot
Cody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx) or [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx)

However, I sometimes find it easy to leave the CheckBoxColumn ReadOnly and explicitly toggle the CheckedState:

```
cell.Value = Not cell.value
```

....and then checkbox values should be as expected in your further processing